# Threejs. Dynamically change the alphaTest of the material

Tags: three.js

Is it possible to dynamically change the alphaTest of the material in Threejs?

Comment: Please, read about [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dynamically change `alphaTest`, but it requires that you also set the `needsUpdate` flag:

```
material.alphaTest = 0.5
material.needsUpdate = true;
```

three.js r.92